# Is iTunes compatible with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, itunes

I frequently transfer music to my Apple iPod.

- Is there any compatible version of iTunes player for Windows 8?
- Will it launch from the Desktop or as a Windows App on the Start Screen?

Comment: The current version of iTunes supports Windows 8

Comment: Is it desktop based or needs to be installed from Windows Store?

Comment: @Saint14 - iTunes is only a desktop application at this time.  Its very unlikely iTunes will be found on the Windows Store.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current version (10.7) installs fine on Windows 8. It creates a tile on the Start screen:

[image]

Opens on the desktop

[image]

Sadly, it is not able to detect my correct language.

Answer (score 2):

Any application that runs on Windows 7 should run fine on Windows 8. It won't run on Windows RT, which can't run desktop apps (apart from special versions of Office, pre-installed with Windows RT).